# How to check the Aws ec2 Instance runtime in hours using lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

How Can I get the running time of  AWS Ec2 Instance more than 4 hours?

Here I tried:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='instance_region_name')
volume = ec2.Volume('vol-id')
print volume.create_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the code below. I also have the requirement to check for instances with a public ip.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='instance_region_name')

instances = ec2_resource.instances.filter(Filters=[{
    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
    'Values': ['running']
}])

for instance in instances:
    names = [x['Value'] for x in instance.tags if x['Key'] == 'Name']
    if len(names) > 0:
        name = names[0]
    else:
        name = ''
    uptime = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - instance.launch_time
    print(name, instance.id, instance.public_ip_address, instance.key_name,
            name, uptime)
    if (not (instance.public_ip_address is None) and uptime > timedelta(hours=4)):
        logger.info('Public instance %s is running for %s', instance.id,
                    uptime)
```